# How to prevent Guest or other account from accessing my secondary drive?

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-explorer, file-permissions

On a shared PC, we can create multiple windows login account. But how can I prevent other user account from accessing my secondary drive? Is it possible to hide the secondary drive from other user?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I prevent other user account from accessing my secondary
> drive? Is it possible to hide the secondary drive from other user?

Right click on the drive, Properties, Security. Give yourself Full Permission first. Then deny permission to all other users (not the Windows stuff - just the users).

I have tested this on a Windows 7 Virtual Machine.

Windows 7 is out of support but this screen shot will help

[image: Security Settings]